# Python ssh using Tor proxy

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, tor

I would like to be able to send data through Tor when I use ssh from Python scripts. Tor works as expected when I use an OpenSSH client to manually ssh to the host. This is my ssh config file. I use connect-proxy with ProxyCommand to route the connections through Tor (again, this works fine via a standard OpenSSH client):

```
host host
user user
hostname host.domain.com
CheckHostIP no
Compression yes
Protocol 2
ProxyCommand connect-proxy -S localhost:9050 %h %p
```

I have this Python test script:

```
import paraproxy
import paramiko

conf = paramiko.SSHConfig()
conf.parse(open('/home/user/.ssh/config'))
host = conf.lookup('host')
print host

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host["hostname"], username=host["user"], password='test')
client.close()
```

This script does ssh to the host, however, it does not use the ProxyCommand in the ssh config file, thus it does not route traffic through Tor. I've tried a few different configurations, but I cannot make it work. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create `ProxyCommand` (a socket-like object) and pass it to `client.connect()`

```
import paramiko

conf = paramiko.SSHConfig()
conf.parse(open('/home/user/.ssh/config'))
host = conf.lookup('host')
print host

proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(host['proxycommand'])

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host["hostname"], username=host["user"], password='test', sock=proxy)
client.close()
```

[Docs for `connect()` method](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/client.py#L234). Note `timeout` parameter. It's always a good idea to specify it if you are doing some automation.

Comment: Have you actually tried to run that code? Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: Yes. But I was poxying via ssh: `ProxyCommand ssh user@proxy.host.tld nc %h %p`

Comment: This works. I missed the part about not using paraproxy. It does not work with that imported. I tried to upvote you, but accidentally downvoted you. But I do accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: My downvote is locked and I cannot change it. However, if you make a small edit to the answer, then I can upvote your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Updated answer with (I think) useful information;)

Comment: this is not working in my case As I am geting packet error reading SSH protocol banner. Please note my host is amazon mainnode instance.