# Cannot create ProxyCommand object in Python

Tags: python, proxy, sftp, paramiko

I need to implement a script that transfers a file via SFTP to a remote server. I have implemented the script in Python using the `paramiko` library. I can get a direct connection working from my home computer without problems but at work I need to connect through a proxy server and that is where I get stuck.

I found a useful post [Python ssh using Tor proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681031/python-ssh-using-tor-proxy) that I thought explained the implementation pretty well but I cannot get the creation of the ProxyCommand working and hence I am stuck.

My (pseudo) code:

```
import paramiko

cmd = 'ssh proxy.server nc %h %p'

proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(cmd)

try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('remote.server', username='ABC', password='123', sock=proxy)
    client.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
finally:
    client.close()
```

The code terminates on the creation of the ProxyCommand (line 3) due to a `FileNotFoundError` with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zzz\Documents\SFTPtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(cmd)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.14.0-py3.3.egg\paramiko\proxy.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.process = Popen(self.cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 820, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    raise WindowsError(*e.args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Can anyone advise what I may be doing wrong? Is the actual command wrong or could there be something missing from my configuration? I run Python 3.3.2 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert - just started using paramiko myself. However I hit a similar error when I used ssh, and it was resolved by specifying the full path of the ssh executable. In my case, it was Linux, so I used `/usr/bin/ssh`. I see you are using Windows - can you figure out the path to your ssh executable and use that instead of just ssh?